# Cannot access files "shared" from service account via drive API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a folder on google drive which was created via a service account, and shared with my user.

- When acting as my user, I can see the folder without issue in the UI.
- When acting as the **service account**, I can list all of the files in the folder via API.

My user has been granted "editor" permission of the folder.

What I need to do is access the list of files in the folder via the API with the service account impersionating my user.

I've setup domain wide delegation and included the scopes:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

This query returns 100 results **when acting as the service account**, however when impersonating my user it returns **0 results.**

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    clientOptions: {
        subject: 'myemail@myorganization.com'
    },
    keyFile: './token.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'],
});

drive.files.list({
    q: "'THE_FOLDER_ID' in parents",
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents,  appProperties)',
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    fields: '*',
    spaces: 'drive'
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.files.length)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" instead of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"